# Non table layout fixed solution for auto shared equal width?

Tags: html, css, layout

Say I have n widgets to be fitted into the same horizontal space taking up 100% of screen width, e.g.

```
<table style="width:100%;text-align:center;table-layout:fixed">
  <tr>
    <td><input/></td>
    <td><span>TEXT</span></td>
    <td><select><option>Something</option></select></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

They share equal width and is adjusted automatically when screen width changes.

Now if one or some of the widgets can be removed (display: none) or simply not there, it is required that the widths do not change, e.g.

```
<table style="width:100%;text-align:center;table-layout:fixed">
  <tr>
    <td><input style="display:none"/></td>
    <td><span>TEXT</span></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Notice how the `span` is still in the middle. It is doable with `table-layout:fixed`.

I wonder if there is an alternative solution, which does not use the `table` tag? Most likely a `div` tag solution with `display:grid` or `display:flex` perhaps?

P.S. no hardcoded number for widths and no computation, just pure CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<div>` with `display: flex;`.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <input class="input" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <span class="span">TEXT</span>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <select class="select">
      <option>Something</option>
    </select> 
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.input {
  display: none;
}
```

And as you can see, when you add `display: none;` to your `<input>`, the column is still there, but empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `display:none` to the `<input>` in the `<td>`, so you are hiding only the `<input>` and `<td>` is still there, but empty.
If you don't want to have the empty space, you have to `<td style="display:none"><input></td>`

Comment: You misread my question, I want the empty spaces, but do not want to use `<table>` tag.

Comment: Then checkout the comment below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64781670/9823216